# XAML collection filling creates duplicates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have created a `UserControl` that receives a collection of objects through its `ContentProperty` attribute and lays them out on the screen by creating a `ContentControl` for each object. In this example those objects are strings to make it simple, but my real application uses more complex objects and some logic to chose adequate DataTemplates; also layout is more complex.

This screenshot shows what I'm aiming for:

[image: What I want]

But I get this instead:

[image: What I get]

The problem is that each instance of `MyControl` is given all strings assigned to all of them, instead of each instance getting only the strings that are specifically assigned to it.

Code for the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <local:MyControl Margin="10">
            <sys:String>AAA</sys:String>
            <sys:String>BBB</sys:String>
            <sys:String>CCC</sys:String>
        </local:MyControl>
        <local:MyControl Margin="10">
            <sys:String>DDD</sys:String>
            <sys:String>EEE</sys:String>
            <sys:String>FFF</sys:String>
        </local:MyControl>
        <local:MyControl Margin="10">
            <sys:String>GGG</sys:String>
            <sys:String>HHH</sys:String>
            <sys:String>III</sys:String>
        </local:MyControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code for the UserControl:

```cs
[ContentProperty(nameof(MyProperty))]
public class MyControl : UserControl, IAddChild
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyProperty), typeof(IList), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new List<object>()));
   public IList MyProperty
   {
      get { return (IList)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
      set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
   }

   public MyControl()
   {
      var sp = new StackPanel();
      Content = sp;

      Loaded += (_, __) =>
      {
         foreach (string e in MyProperty)
            sp.Children.Add(new ContentControl { Content = e });
      };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserControl`s reuse the **same** list instance created as default value in the `PropertyMetadata`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/collection-type-dependency-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#initializing-the-collection-beyond-the-default-value) of collection type dependency properties:

> If your property is a reference type, the default value specified in dependency property metadata is **not a default value per instance**; instead it is a default value that applies to **all instances** of the type.

> To correct this problem, you must reset the collection dependency property value to a unique instance, as part of the class constructor call.

To do this in your code, create and set a new list instance in the constructor like this.

```
public MyControl()
{
   MyProperty = new List<object>();

   // .. rest of the constructor.
}
```

---

Bonus answer: If you use a collection type property that should not be writeable from outside of the control, you might consider making the dependency property read-only like below.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(MyProperty))]
public class MyControl : UserControl, IAddChild
{
   private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey MyPropertyPropertyKey =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(MyProperty), typeof(IList),
         typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new List<object>()));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
      MyPropertyPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

   public IList MyProperty => (IList)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);

   public MyControl()
   {
      SetValue(MyPropertyPropertyKey, new List<object>());

      var sp = new StackPanel();
      Content = sp;

      Loaded += (_, __) =>
      {
         foreach (string e in MyProperty)
            sp.Children.Add(new ContentControl { Content = e });
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: In this case I prefer to keep the property settable because it allows me to bind it to a list provided on the ViewModel instead of defining the list on the View like I did on my example. I'd like to keep both options open.

Comment: I researched more into the topic of DependencyProperty initialization and found this blog post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191002-00/?p=102950 which explains this topic in quite a lot of detail.